# Smillaenlarger on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, photo-editing

I've been trying to install Smillaenlarger (a photo enlarging app that eliminates aliasing; making nearly perfect enlargements) on Ubuntu 20.04. I had it on a previous install of the same OS but can't remember how I got it to work. I've tried compiling from source, and get no errors, but it won't start. I tried a Debian .deb file (had to add a few libraries according to the site) but it still won't install (and one of the needed dependencies required removing another app that I wanted to keep so I reversed what I had done). I'm thinking (desperate now) of installing the Windows version under WINE, but I'd prefer not to do that if there's another way. I don't think I ran it under WINE before, at least as I remember. If anyone has it working, please tell me how you did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lupoDharkael/smilla-enlarger

It is indicated that
`apt install -y git g++ build-essential qt5-qmake qt5-default`
... will install what you need w.r.t software.

To compile the sources:
`Compilation: run qmake && make in the main directory.`

If no errors appear, it usually means there will be an executable file somewhere among the sources. Exactly where "depends" (on many factors), and *in case of errors; you need to **understand** each problem to be able to correct them...*

On success, Often: `make install` will make the software available for "normal" use.
As I have NOT checked / tried this - I might be wrong this time.

*Happy hacking.*

Comment: I did exactly as directed and still no go. I'm getting "Error 1" at the end of the compiling process. I tried 3 different (zip) versions. All results are the same. There's a note on the site describing the exact issue I'm seeing. I set up a Windows version in q4wine. Works OK and I don't use it a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Well `Error 1` is nothing more than `make` (probably) saying `it failed`. You would have needed to include the actual first indicated fault - at least.